# Apply Glow Effect Filter to Anchor Tag with Transparent Path Child SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I would like to create an image map by using an SVG to create the clickpoints. I have been asked to add a glow to the anchor on hover, which I'm currently doing by applying a filter to the anchor tag with CSS on hover. However, the glow only works if the path that is a child of the anchor has a solid fill color, as seen in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/asanchez64/pen/oNLvrwp). The SVG used is the following:

```
<svg version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 3686 2074"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <filter id="white-glow"
                x="-5000%"
                y="-5000%"
                width="10000%"
                height="10000%">
            <feFlood result="flood"
                     flood-color="#00bbdc"
                     flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
            <feComposite in="flood"
                         result="mask"
                         in2="SourceGraphic"
                         operator="in"></feComposite>
            <feMorphology in="mask"
                          result="dilated"
                          operator="dilate"
                          radius="10"></feMorphology>
            <feGaussianBlur in="dilated"
                            result="blurred"
                            stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
      <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        path:hover {
            filter: url(#white-glow);
        }

        a:hover {
            filter: url(#white-glow);
            text-decoration: none;
            fill: #00BBDC;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        a:hover text {
            filter: invert(62%) sepia(97%) saturate(3198%) hue-rotate(150deg) brightness(98%) contrast(101%);
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

    </defs>
            <g>
        <a href="google.com"
           target="_top">
            <path d="m473.3 564.3-0.6911 207 412.4 78.63-0.4043-180.9z"
                  style="fill:white;stroke-opacity:0;"
                  cursor="pointer"
                  pointer-events="all" />
            <text transform="rotate(10.2 222.2 851.7)"
                  style="fill:#808080;font-family:'sans-serif';font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;shape-inside:url(#rect898);white-space:pre"
                  xml:space="preserve">
                <tspan x="304.74805"
                       y="648.91602">
                    <tspan>Ask the experts</tspan>
                </tspan>
            </text>
        </a>

    </g>
</svg>
```

However, I would like to accomplish the same glow effect on hover while giving the path a fill value of "transparent".

Could you please give me some guidance as to how to proceed in order to accomplish the same end result that was referenced before while keeping the fill value of the path within the anchor tag to "transparent"? I've read the following [Smashing Magazine article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/) in which the author talks about the difference between painted and visible SVG elements. Also, according to an answer to [How to have a drop shadow on a transparent rect svg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55349946/1698964),

> You can't do this if the original is a fully transparent shape - because of reasons - but you can do this starting from an almost completely transparent original shape and end up with a fully transparent shape surrounded by a normal drop shadow.

I used the work around provided and published a [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/asanchez64/pen/gOMYNrd) with it. However, the "Text" child in the anchor tag gets hidden on hover although it's still present in the SVG. Indeed, the filter is blurring away the text. Could you please tell me is there is any other way?

Thanks for your share of expertise on this one.

Comment: path:hover instead of a:hover maybe. Not sure what you actually want it to look like though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the contents of the original graphic, then you need to add another line to your filter which pastes the original content on top of your glow.

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        background:orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg version="1.1"
         viewBox="0 0 3686 2074"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <filter id="white-glow"
                    x="-5000%"
                    y="-5000%"
                    width="10000%"
                    height="10000%">
                <feFlood result="flood"
                         flood-color="#00bbdc"
                         flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
                <feComposite in="flood"
                             result="mask"
                             in2="SourceGraphic"
                             operator="in"></feComposite>
                <feMorphology in="mask"
                              result="dilated"
                              operator="dilate"
                              radius="10"></feMorphology>
                <feGaussianBlur in="dilated"
                                result="blurred"
                                stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
          
            <filter id="trans-shadow">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 1 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 1 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 100 0"
                                       result="boostedInput"/>
                                       
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
  <feComposite operator="out" in2="boostedInput"/>
  <feComposite operation="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
        </defs>
        <style>
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
 
            }



            a:hover {
                filter: url(#trans-shadow);
                text-decoration: none;
                fill: #00BBDC;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            a:hover text {
                filter: invert(62%) sepia(97%) saturate(3198%) hue-rotate(150deg) brightness(98%) contrast(101%);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
        <g>
            <a href="google.com"
               target="_top" pointer-events="all" >
                <path d="m473.3 564.3-0.6911 207 412.4 78.63-0.4043-180.9z"
                      style="fill:white;fill-opacity="0.01"stroke-opacity:0;" visibility="visible"
                       />
                <text transform="rotate(10.2 222.2 851.7)"
                      style="fill:#808080;font-family:'sans-serif';font-size:40px;line-height:1.25;shape-inside:url(#rect898);white-space:pre"
                      xml:space="preserve">
                    <tspan x="304.74805"
                           y="648.91602">
                        <tspan>Ask the experts</tspan>
                    </tspan>
                </text>
            </a>

        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```